# Get Values inside an ItemTemplate of a ListView C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, itemtemplate

```
 <ListView Name="myList" Background="Transparent" Margin="15,88,15,15">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                <Grid Height="100">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Margin="5">
                        <TextBlock Name="xName" Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="30" Margin="10,0,5,0" FontWeight="Medium"/>
                        <TextBlock Name="xNo" Text="{Binding No}" FontSize="25" Margin="10,0,5,0" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"/>
                    </StackPanel>

                        <Grid Grid.Column="1" Margin="5">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <RadioButton Grid.Column="0" Name="r1" Content="1" Width="10" Margin="5,15,-2,5"/>
                            <RadioButton Grid.Column="1" Name="r2" Content="2" Width="10" Margin="5,15,-2,5"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                   </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

---

Now I want to retrieve each item in ListView i.e, the controls in it. The TextBlocks content and to know which RadioButton is selected.
I tried taking classes like this

```
    public class Att
    {
        public string Name;
        public string No;
        public RadioButton r1;
        public RadioButton r2;
    }
```

---

There are separate sources for the content of the TextBoxes in the ListView. They come from different classes. I tried retrieving the items using above class Att.
But it is showing some type conversion errors. Please anyone help me! I'm a beginner.
Thanks is advance.

Comment: What are you using MVVM ?

Comment: Yes. I'm trying to develop a database based app for Windows Phone 8.1.

Comment: I see you use bindings in some text blocks. You should use the same in every control wich contains some data. This way you can work with data itself, not collection of controls. 
What you're trying to do is not really WPF-style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the support!

Well I tried doing this on my own and finally I got it. What I really wanted is to know which RadioButton is checked. I tried taking class Att for retrieving the items in ListView. I made modifications to the Att Class and added properties r1 and r2 of type bool instead of RadioButton and binded this property to the IsChecked property of the RadioButton in XAML and also mode of binding is TwoWay. So the changes done in the XAML can be reflected in the source list of items.